# Арифметические операции над датой и временем

Tags: mysql, время, php, дата, javascript

Здравствуйте, возник следующий вопрос, в БД нужно хранить дату и время (к примеру, 12:30:00 01-06-2012), затем в скрипте нужно получить дату человека который зашел, и из данных из БД вычесть полученные от пользователя данные, и вывести результат по примеру: 2д. 14-30-45.

Переворошил справочник, но что-то без безрезультатно, подскажите, как такое сделать? В каком формате хранить данные в БД, как выполнить арифметическую операцию над датой? Аналог втретил на сайте 2012год.ру (не реклама), у них похожее в шапке.

Answer (score 2):

В php есть класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php) и там есть метод [sub](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php)